# React-navigation tabs not navigating back to the last viewed tab

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation

I have a built a tab navigator in my app using react-navigation-tabs. I have three tabs which are embedded in a stack navigator.I can access the 3rd tab and access that respective screen.When I come back to the tab, I should navigate to the 3rd tab ideally. In my case, I'm landing on the first tab and have to navigate to the 3rd one all over again. 
Can anyone please suggest a solution for this?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you use ```navigation.navigate()``` or ```navigation.push()```?

Comment: @Aishwarya Vaidyanath it would be great if you share what have you tried till now(Source code) so that one can exactly understand what you have done and trying to achive.

Comment: @VigneshVPai I used navigation.navigate() to the Stack navigator that houses the entire tab since I directly could not navigate to the specific tab.

Comment: Do you mean to say from your third tab, you moved to another screen with navigate() ? If yes, then how did you come back to tab? By pressing back or did you do navigate again?